# how to enable gzip in an angular 5 project

Tags: typescript, webpack, angular5

I am working a Project. In which, I am using angular cli(1.7.4), angular core(1.0.0-beta.2) and webpack(1.10.2).

But speed is very slow, Google Page Speed insight told me some point to increase the speed of website.

1. Enable Text Compression
2. Defer offscreen images
3. Serve images in next-gen formats

How we can done Compression in this project

```
// Work around for https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin"); // Tried Rup

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts',
    // This is an example of Static prerendering (generative)
    prerender: './prerender.ts'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  // Make sure we include all node_modules etc
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/,],
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

Comment: gzip is enabled in the server, where the content is served from

Comment: How you can say compression is enabled in the server. while served files are not compressed to the client.

Comment: So if you didn't enable on the server, they won't be served as compressed... you have to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 5, please consider updating to the following version:

- @angular-devkit/core         7.2.1
- Angular CLI: 7.2.1

It will build you project with webpack 4 which is very faster than previous version.

Do not forget to use AOT for the production build.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this task is by letting the server do it for you. For example in IIS you can enable "Dynamic content compression".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpCompression/#003

In your case you need to check the web server you use to enable this feature.